# How to find if the point is within a bounding box in Tile38?

Tags: geohashing, tile38

I would like to know how to find if the point is within bounding box in tile 38. My bounding boxes are defined by 2 geohashes of 7-charachter length.

I have the following use case related to real-time geo data.
There is a stream of points about 1000 per second.  Also there is a collection and a stream of rectangular polygons defined by 2 geohashes of 7-charachter length. These bounding boxes are created and deleted with the rate of 300 per second. On average there is 10000 live bounding boxes.

For each point I need to know within what bounding boxes it is.
Note a lot of bounding boxes overlap by 90% of their area. If you can, please suggest the best indexing algorithm to index these bounding boxes or maybe a smart algorythm to combine them so that there is no need to check point against each of the 10000 bounding box.

I thought that tile38 is the best solution for this use case. Please, let me know if there other more suitable solutions.